# Répéter ou omettre le "de" dans une énumération?

Tags: prépositions, énumération

Je suis en train de corriger un aperçu et je suis tombé sur une phrase qui me semble bien bizarre.

La phrase est:

> Cependant, les populations d'éléphants, de gorilles, de lions, de rhinocéros et de léopards sont menacées par le braconnage.

Peut-on omettre le "de" et donc écrire:

> Cependant, les populations d'éléphants, gorilles, lions, rhinocéros et léopards sont menacées par le braconnage.

? Ou est-ce faux?

Answer (score 5):

*Le bon usage* a un article consacré exactement à la possibilité de laisser tomber le **de** lors de certaines circonstances, c’est-à-dire lorsque les membres de l’énumération...

> 1. ...sont des expressions et locutions toutes faites: *École **des** arts et métiers.*
> 2. ...représentent le(s) même(s) êtres ou objets: *Il débrouille de même l’horrible chaos **des** deux empires, le Babylonien et l’Assyrien.* (La Bruyère)
> 3. ...désignent un groupe ou une idée unique: *Les adresses **des** amis et connaissances.*
> 4. ...sont des nombres joints par *ou* et marquant une approximation: *Un délai **de** trois ou quatre mois.*

Je verrais bien votre exemple correspondre au point 3 : toutes les populations dont vous parlez correspondent à celles de gros animaux africains menacées par le braconnage. Il s’agit bien d’une énumération ciblée englobant les différents éléments d’un tout particulier, donc aucun problème pour couper, et la phrase suivante est selon moi tout à fait acceptable :

> Cependant, les populations **d**’éléphants, gorilles, lions, rhinocéros et léopards sont menacées par le braconnage.

Comment: Je vous remercie chaleureusement, Monsieur. Ce livre me semble un très bon investissement (:

Comment: Quelqu'un intéressé au français et à la grammaire y retourne très souvent lorsqu'il en fait l'achat. C'est un coup à donner, mais ça dure des décennies sans réellement prendre un coup de vieux.

Answer (score 2):

As redundant and cumbersome as it may seem, you indeed need to place the preposition "de" each and every time.

You might well come across a similar preposition *pile-up* such as:

> Je vais aller ***au*** supermarché, puis ***à la*** pharmacie et ***aux*** impôts.

Not correct:

> <s>Je vais aller ***au*** supermarché, puis ***la*** pharmacie et ***les*** impôts.</s>

Comment: Merci beaucoup!

Comment: I strongly disagree concerning *"de"* in the example provided by Adam.

Comment: I'd be delighted if you were to elaborate on your point (:

Comment: I don't know the rule but as a French speaker, both your examples seem perfectly correct. Still I agree concerning the example of Alone-zee with *"à"*. But I can find examples with *"à"* where you can omit it ("j'ai dit bonjour à ma mère, mon père, mon frère et mon oncle").

Comment: @Alone-zee This example has nothing to do with the OP's example.